# Prevent DataNucleus transactions on every read

Tags: java, database, postgresql, configuration, datanucleus

Is it possible to have read queries in Datanucleus without creating transactions? 
I would like to have non-blocking dirty read in my application but even without creating transactions I see it in postgre logs. Setting property "datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" to true doesn't help.

```
entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(); 
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from managers where department_id='1' and account_id = '1'", User.class); 
entityManager.close();
```

Here is a part of postgresql-9.5-main.log

```
2018-12-13 14:43:42 user@test LOG: execute <unnamed>: SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL 
2018-12-13 14:43:42 user@test LOG: execute <unnamed>: BEGIN 2018-12-13 14:43:42 user@test LOG: execute <unnamed>: select * from managers where department_id='9' and account_id = '9' 
2018-12-13 14:43:42 user@test LOG: execute S_2: COMMIT
```

Maybe it is just a misunderstanding or I haven't formulated my question properly.

I have dug into postgresql driver library I see that after few DataNucleus calls control goes to HikariProxyPreparedStatement and then to PostgresqlExecutorImpl. There is a call of QueryExecutorImpl.sendQueryPreamble() which calls  sendOneQuery() with beginTransactionQuery as a parameter. So beginTransactionQuery it is a SimpleQuery with just "BEGIN" sql string. I assume that it is a transaction opening.

Am I right? If so, how to avoid transaction creation? If not please correct me.

Comment: NonTransactionRead DEFAULTS to TRUE, which simply says *allow operations without JDO transactions*. You haven't said what happens when you execute an operation without a JDO transaction (and post the code)!

Comment: @BillyFrost thx for the response. It is my first question here, and I am not able to edit it.

`entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from managers where department_id='1' and  account_id = '1'", User.class);

        entityManager.close();`

Comment: A "transaction" is not shown in any PostgreSQL logs ... that is a JDBC/SQL connection being handed out and closed. A transaction is managed by the JDO/JPA provider, which will manage any connection(s) being used. The DataNucleus log tells you what it is doing

Comment: I have enabled DataNucleus logs. And you are right there are no messages about an opening transaction. But I see it in postgresql-9.5-main.log
`2018-12-13 14:43:42 user@test LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL
2018-12-13 14:43:42 user@test LOG:  execute <unnamed>: BEGIN
2018-12-13 14:43:42 user@test LOG:  execute <unnamed>: select * from managers where department_id='9' and  account_id = '9'
2018-12-13 14:43:42 user@test LOG:  execute S_2: COMMIT`

Comment: which is a connection being allocated, and then committed. An `EntityManager` in general will use a single connection, so you get one when opening it, and release it at close.

Comment: Thanks for your help  @BillyFrost . But it is still not clear for me. Maybe it is not related to DataNucleus itself or Hikari. I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found what is the case.

DataNucleus runs all queries in transactions except queries which have TransactionIsolation.NONE even if a transaction is not created. Any connection for a non-transaction query will be switched to autocommit true and mostly for all other levels, it will be switched to false. Any kind of autocmmit true query leads to sending BEGIN query which starts a transaction.

So it looks like it is impossible to do reads from PostgreSQL without making transactions which will be created in any case because PostgreSQL doesn’t support TransactionIsolation.NONE.  You can figure it out if take a look on the code of [ConnectionFactoryImpl](https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-rdbms/blob/master/src/main/java/org/datanucleus/store/rdbms/ConnectionFactoryImpl.java)

It would be nice if somebody from DataNucleus developers clarifies that.